# Using Cucumber feature file, TestNG as a suite, how do I get results scenario-wise along with steps result list when run

Tags: cucumber, testng, bdd, cucumber-java, java-17

I am working on an Appium test automation with JDK 17.0.7, Cucumber-java 7.12.1, cucumber-testng 7.12.1, testng 7.8.0.

I am getting the result tree as shown here.[![What I am getting][1]][1]

Where as I would like this type of tree representation:[![what I am hoping to get the tree node][2]][2]

Here is **testng.xml file** and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
   <test name="Pixel4">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>
        <parameter name="udid" value="9B081FFAZ00D09"/>
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="Pixel 4"/>
        <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000"/>
        <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.MyTestNGRunnerTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
        </suite>
```

Here is **feature file**:

```
Feature: Dashboard scenarios

    Background: Pre-Conditions
        Given launch the app

    @iOS @Android @venkata
    Scenario: Verify Group activation
        Given user is in landing page
        And Create Group Activation Link
        When user selects "Get Started" option
        And user selects "Login with Activation Link"
        And user enters activation link
        And user taps "continue" option
        And user allows "All the Permission"
        And user allows device setting "permissions"
        Then user should see "DashBoard" page

    @iOS @Android @venkata
    Scenario: Verify Dashboard Page UI Elements
        Given user is in "Dashboard" Page
        Then user verifies dashboard page elements

    @iOS @Android @venkata
    Scenario: Verify Dashboard Page Menu Navigation
        Given user is in "Dashboard" Page
        When user selects menu option
        Then user should navigated to menu page
        When user selects Apps option
        Then user should navigated to Apps page
        When user selects Web option
        Then user should navigated to Web page
        When user selects Device option
        Then user should navigated to Device page
        When user selects Network option
        Then user should navigated to Network page
        When user selects Threat Zone option
        Then user should navigated to Threat Zone page
        When user selects Tag Tracker option
        Then user should navigated to Tag Tracker page
        When user selects Tutorials option
        Then user should navigated to Tutorials page
```

Here is the **cucumberOptions** from **MyTestNGTestRunner.java** file

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "summary", "me.jvt.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/cucumber-html-reports"}
        ,features = {"src/test/resources"}
        ,glue = {"stepdef"}
        ,dryRun=false
        ,monochrome=true
        ,tags = "@venkata"
)
```

````
public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickle, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
    testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickle.getPickle());
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] scenarios() {
    return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDownClass() {

    //code....
}```

**Please help me with what I am supposed to do ?
I checked the examples at [cucumber-jvm at github][3]**


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWr7h.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsObm.png
  [3]: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/examples
````